# Reference Error: MessageEmbed is not defined on my poll command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, I am coding a poll bot and I was making something as to where if a user says only 'poll', the system responds with an embed telling them to use the right command. However, I got a reference error: MessageEmbed is not defined. Please help me with this. Code is shown as below:

```
            const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(0xFFC300)
            .setTitle("Initiate Poll")
            .setDescription("p!poll to initiate a simple yes or no poll!");

            if(!args[1]){
                message.channel.send(Embed);
            }
        break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import `MessageEmbed` in one of the following ways:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
```

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
```

```js
import { MessageEmbed } from 'discord.js';
```